# Understanding UnsafeMutablePointers and how to deal with them

Tags: swift, pointers

Could anyone please explain or give a link to a good guide on **UnsafeMutablePointer**s? I can't freaking understand how they work and how to modify them.

Here's an example.

I am migrating my custom video player to **Swift** from **Objective-C**.

In **Objective-C** I create **MTAudioProcessingTapRef** using a **callbacks** structure:

```
MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks callbacks;
callbacks.clientInfo = (__bridge void *)(self);
callbacks.init = initTap;
// Init other fields of callbacks
MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks, kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap);
```

Here I cast retainable **MyClass** pointer to void pointer to use it as **clientInfo** later.

> (__bridge T) op casts the operand to the destination type T. If T is a
>   non-retainable pointer type, then op must have a retainable object
>   pointer type.

Then **tap** gets initialized:

```
void initTap(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, void *clientInfo, void **tapStorageOut)
{
    *tapStorageOut = clientInfo;
}
```

Here I pass a **pointer to self into tapStorageOut** to grab self inside tap's callback function.

And then processing is performed:

```
void processTap(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount numberFrames, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags, AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut,
         CMItemCount *numberFramesOut, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut)
{
    MyClass *self = (__bridge MyClass *) MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap);
    MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut, flagsOut, NULL, numberFramesOut);
}
```

Now I have a few issues here.

1. I did found how to cast types into other types. Here are the functions:

   ```
   func bridge<type : AnyObject>(object : type) -> UnsafeRawPointer
   {
       let unmanagedObject : Unmanaged = Unmanaged.passUnretained(object)
       let unsafeMutableRawObject : UnsafeMutableRawPointer = unmanagedObject.toOpaque()
       return UnsafeRawPointer(unsafeMutableRawObject)
   }

   func bridge<type : AnyObject>(pointer : UnsafeRawPointer) -> type
   {
       let unmanagedObject : Unmanaged<type> = Unmanaged<type>.fromOpaque(pointer)
       let object : type = unmanagedObject.takeUnretainedValue()
       return object
   }
   ```

   but I have zero understanding of what all of these letters do. Some explanation of this by one of you guys would be awesome.
2. Let's look at **initTap** function. Here I have a pointer A (**tapStorageOut**) that references a pointer B that references some data. I change pointer B to pointer C, which is my **clientInfo**. Clear as a sunny day.

   Now, in **Swift** **tapStorageOut** is *UnsafeMutablePointer* now, whatever that thing is. And I have zero clue about how to deal with it.
3. In **Objective-C** when I process data I have a **bufferListInOut** variable which is a pointer to *AudioBufferList* structure. 
   In **Swift** however it has *UnsafeMutablePointer* type. So again, not understanding how UnsafeMutablePointers work prevents me from grabbing the data.

Comment: Im having the exact same issue with assigning  clientInfo to tapStorageOut in Swift. Did you find a way to write it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main use of a pointer in Swift is working with C API and such. For the most part you should use reference semantics instead of pointers in Swift. That means using a `class`, when you pass a `class` instance around it automatically passes a reference instead of making a copy. Thus, it saves resources and any changes you make to a reference to the instance are reflected everywhere it is referenced. A Swift class is generally instantiated on the heap.

When you convert Objective-C to Swift pointers to objects are generally treated as references to those objects. Internally, a Swift reference is pretty much semantic sugar for a pointer.

Swift structures, on the other hand, have value semantics. They are generally instantiated on the stack and when you pass them around they are copied rather than passing a reference. The same goes when you mutate them, a new instance is created with the new values and it is swapped for the old instance. There are some tricks done where a `struct` will wrap a block of memory and hold a pointer to that memory. Thus a `struct` may have some reference semantics internally but try to avoid breaking the expectation of a `struct`'s value being copied when it's passed around.

Some good reading:

- [Fundamentals of Callbacks for Swift Developers](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/02/15/fundamentals-of-callbacks-for-swift-developers/)
- [Thinking in Swift, Part 3: Struct vs. Class](http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/2015/10/03/thinking-in-swift-3/)
- [Lazy Initialization with Swift](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/)

I'd read these and take a good, hard look at your architecture before trying to use stuff like `UnsafeMutablePointer`. Yes, they are useful in some circumstances but they can be a pain to work with and are not necessary for most pure Swift tasks. Especially in a Swift API!

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll investigate into them. As for lack of necessity in `UnsafeMutablePointer`, I am working with audio a lot, where the thing is vastly used. Hence I have to find a way to get around with Swift unsafe stuff.

Comment: @Igor I feel the issue here is that you are digging into very low level stuff when it's the higher level API that's getting into your way. Your code is extremely "object-oriented C" and uses some older concepts that are not in-step with modern Objective-C. Trying to translate those concepts to Swift can be a huge pain and result in very non-Swifty code. Particularly how you have your `callbacks` structure defined, it really should be completely reworked to the simpler form Swift allows.

Comment: @Igor It looks like a step in the right direction but I'd have to see more of your API to be sure.